# Can I use a regular expression to convert these examples to markdown?

Tags: regex, markdown

I have been working on a [google docs to markdown converter](https://github.com/clearf/gdocs2md/blob/master/converttomarkdown.gapps) to convert post written in google docs to something that can be easily used within jekyll. Unfortunately, google docs has some foibles that make conversion non-trivial. For example, [kramdown emphasis](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#emphasis) requires that text being emphasized be "surrounded" by emphasis markers, where:

> Surrounded means that the starting delimiter must not be followed by a space and that the stopping delimiter must not be preceded by a space.

Within google docs, on the other hand, one can have whitespace emphasized, which will generate output that kramdown cannot parse.

*em * will produce *em *, not *em*.

I've written a regular expression that works to match and substitute this incorrect emphasis, but I'm stuck on a corner case.

`/(\*+)(\s*\b)([^\*]*)(\b\s*)(\*+)/g` will properly match (and thus allow for substitution each of the emphasis regions below):

> `*** Strong italic text ***, and even just *strong text *, when rendered in * Markdown*, doesn't like *spaces * around the boundaries of the stars.`

but chokes when there is emphasis within a word.

> `* You can see it also within the li**n**es here.   *`

(the match now stops with the *s within "lines" and does not catch the " "s before the terminating *.)

All this is clear on [regexr](http://regexr.com/3ab16).

How do I edit the regex to properly handle this corner case, i.e., ignoring *s that are (properly) embedded within words?

Comment: If anyone has an alternate methodology of google docs -> jekyll, I'm also all ears, though I have found that going through HTML requires a separate stylesheet to properly render each document's formatting.

Comment: Attempting to parse a non-regular language with regular expressions is not recommended.

Comment: note that there isn't a word boundary exists after dot and a space.

Comment: @clearf you mean this https://regex101.com/r/jF5vL3/1 ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj That's very close, thanks. Multiple spaces between the words and the \*s aren't captured, just the space right before.

Comment: @DanD. Any suggestion for other tools?

Comment: i don't know what you mean..  spaces after the dot?

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes, that's what I mean (if I'm interpreting the output  of your snippet on regex101 correctly). For example, match #5, it appears that that the space before the final \* is part of group 3?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69979/discussion-between-clearf-and-avinash-raj).

Comment: @clearf see https://regex101.com/r/jF5vL3/2

Comment: I would export to HTML from Google Docs, then use [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to convert to Markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this.

```
\B(\*+)(\s*)(?:\b\*+\b|[^*\s]|\s(?=\w))*(\s*)(\*+)\B
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jF5vL3/2)

Comment: This does look like it handles all these corner cases, thanks. Could you explain two things:

* Why does the statement need to be surrounded by \B, and
* What are the distinct parts of the middle match capturing:
`(?:\b\*+\b|[^*\s]|\s(?=\w))`